# taskhostw.exe spawns multiple ngen.exe's, consuming tons of CPU and RAM

Tags: windows-10, ngen

I'm on Windows 10 Enterprise (v1607) and I've got the `taskhostw.exe` process spawning lots of `ngen.exe` processes which eat up CPU and overheat my machine. I cannot kill either of these in Process Explorer (access denied), so I'm looking for advice on how to fix this.

And yes, I've Googled this, found no good resolution, really.

Comment: disable automatic and auto maintenance tasks in task scheduler

Comment: @magicandre1981 seems to have done the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Native Image Generator (Ngen.exe) is a tool that improves the performance of managed applications. So it could be related to an application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx

Please check the symptom in a clean boot environment.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

To analyze the issue deeply, we could use the Windows Performance toolkit tool to collect more information.
Here are links for reference:

Windows performance recorder

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/windows-performance-recorder/a1648e8c-50c7-4243-9f1d-4216385c7ff3

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Ngen tasks are present in the Task Scheduler. In Windows 10, you can do a fix by doing the following:

1. Go into Task Scheduler
2. Navigate the folder structure to `Task Scheduler Library/Microsoft/Windows/.NET Framework`
3. Find all tasks that begin with `.NET Framework NGEN` and either disable or outright delete them.

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

**Update:** ever since I posted the above fix, I've had the same issue pop up *again*. This time round, the culprit was `PerfWatson2.exe` which is part of Visual Studio. To kill it, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662444/how-to-disable-perfwatson2-exe-from-visual-studio-2017).