# ngen.exe uses 60% CPU

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, ngen

[ngen.exe in Process Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68dL6.jpg)

Sometimes, out of the blue, my Laptop starts using up to 60% CPU for a while, 15 min or so or more. It turns out, that there is a process called ngen.exe which keeps starting and stopping.

This is only visible with [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) though. The regular Task Manager does not show this phenomena, it just shows 60% CPU usage.

I found a "solution" to the problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1205384/taskhostw-exe-spawns-multiple-ngen-exes-consuming-tons-of-cpu-and-ram), but I also heard that disabling ngen is a "extremly bad idea".

Any ideas, why it is a bad idea?

Comment: I do not have ngen running on my computers here. Try this fix:    https://superuser.com/questions/1126078/ngen-exe-high-cpu-windows-10-assemblies-uninstall-endless-loop

Comment: “why it is a bad idea?” - It will reduce the performance of manager applications but that performance drop might not be something you can measure and/or notice. Instead of disabling it you should use the provided script in the accepted answer

Comment: @Ramhound If I can not measure and/or notice a performance drop, what's the relevancy anyway?

Comment: @user3797717 - On a slower machine a 5% performance drop is noticed.  On a faster machine you might not notice that kind of performance drop.  If you are performing a benchmark you absolutely will see the drop, but a benchmark, isn’t always the real world.